# In Android, is there a more elegant way to retrieve application context inside a inner class?

Tags: android

In Android, is there a more elegant way to **retrieve application context** inside a inner class rather than passing context as a parameter?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    class SeekBarChangeListener implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
        {
            private Context context;
            private TextView distanceTextView;

            public SeekBarChangeListener(Context context, TextView distanceTextView) {
                this.context = context;
                this.distanceTextView = distanceTextView;
            }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as its an inner class of an Activity, you could use:

```
this.context = MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

call `MainActivity.this` from the inner class and it will give you the Activity context object.

You should **not** use the `applicationContext` i.e. calling `getApplicationContext()` unless you really need it, but from your example code you have, `Activity context` should be enough